# ASP.NET MVC4 phonegap authentication

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, cordova

I'm developing a mobile application using Phonegap. Now I've been doing some research for authentication and I can't seem to find a propper answer/example of how this should be done.  I've got an ASP.NET MVC4 backend so I would like to use ajax calls to call the methods I need.

Now the login at the beginning of the App isn't that difficult. But the problem is that I don't want the methods to be publicly accessed. Within the webapplication I solved this by using the [Authorize] tag above my Controller method. But this doesn't seem to work within a Phonegap App because you can't save cookies and have sessions like in a your browser.

I did read that you can use Phonegap localstorage as an alternative to cookies and sessions. But I'm not sure how to apply this.. I also came across the suggestion to store the username and password in a database and give it in each ajax call so I could authenticate each time. But this didn't seem like a favorable and secure solution.

I hope my question is clear and you guys can point out some suggestions or examples. I apologize for my grammar, English isn't my native language. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you can not use cookies/sessions with phonegap. Local storage/DB is the best way to go to store persistent data. If you need to simple store some key/value pairs, use the local storage. If you want to store more complex data or take advantage of database capabilities, use the database. Take a look at [this documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) for using local storage or the DB.

*Note: the documentation I linked is for phonegap v.3.0. If you are using a different version, change the version number in the top right of the page I linked.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation. In order to solve the problem I decided to use Thinktecture framework Session Token. It allows to to authenticate once using for example Basic Authentication, then you can request a token that can be passed among requests and can be store in you local storage. This way you won't have to store the user and password in insecure locations.